# How can I find the Quandl codes for metals?

Tags: curated-data, finance

Probably not the right site to ask this, but how can I find out the Quandl codes for different commodities? For example, gold against USD? Tried `"CURRFX/XAUUSD"`, but no joy. Here is the code for plotting GBP against USD:

```
DateListPlot[
  Rest @ 
    QuandlFinancialData["CURRFX/USDGBP", 
      startDate -> "2016-6-1", endDate -> "2016-6-23", column -> 2], 
  ImageSize -> 400]
```

Comment: Would something like this free Quandl database link to the World Gold Council (https://www.quandl.com/data/WGC) work for you? The code seems to be "WGC/GOLD_DAILY_USD". I found that through [their database browser](https://www.quandl.com/browse?idx=database-browser).

Comment: @MarcoB It works - thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! Would you mind putting together a quick self-answer, pointing to the ``QuandlLink` `` package, and to the database browser as well, for future reference? This could be very useful for future searchers!

Comment: @MarcoB will do

Answer (score 4):

*Answer posted for the benefit of future users of the [Quandl package for MMA](https://github.com/bajracha71/Quandl-Mathematica-QuandlLink) by [Anmol Bajracharya](http://community.wolfram.com/web/anmolb/home), also described in [this Wolfram Community post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/540228).*

Thanks to @MarcoB's search through Quandl's [database browser](https://www.quandl.com/browse?idx=database-browser), he found a link to the [World Gold Council](https://www.quandl.com/data/WGC). Using the code `"WGC/GOLD_DAILY_USD"` works in this case:

```
<< QuandlLink`

DateListPlot[
  Rest@ 
    QuandlFinancialData[
      "WGC/GOLD_DAILY_USD", 
      startDate -> "2016-6-1", endDate -> "2016-6-23", 
      column -> 2
    ], 
   ImageSize -> 400
 ]
```

produces:

[image: timeline plot of gold price in USD in June 2016]

Comment: Martin Thanks for drafting this.

Answer (score 2):

Slight modification to martin's answer to address recent changes in Ma.

```
QuandlOneSeries[symbol_, stDate_, endDate_] := Module[{data, dates, datav, datats},
  data = Import[StringJoin["https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/", symbol, 
     "/data.csv?start_date=", stDate, "&end_date=", endDate, 
     "&order=asc"]];
  dates = ToExpression[StringSplit[data[[2 ;;, 1]], "-"]];
  datav = data[[2 ;;, 2]];
  datats = TimeSeries[datav, {dates}];
  Return[datats]]
```

Using above function, data can be downloaded and `DateListPlot` can be used to plot it as follows:

```
DateListPlot[QuandlOneSeries["WGC/GOLD_DAILY_USD", "1975-03-31", "2019-05-31"],
GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, get an API key from [here](https://www.quandl.com/?modal=register) *(free)*, and use something like the following:

```
quandl[dataset_, startdate_, enddate_, apikey_] := 
Import[StringJoin["https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/", 
dataset, ".json?api_key=", apikey, "&start_date=", startdate, 
"&end_date=", enddate]][[1, 2, 6, 2]];
```

which gives

```
DateListPlot[quandl["WGC/GOLD_DAILY_USD", "1980-01-01", "2016-06-24", 
(*your API key*)]]
```

[image]